# How do I get Excel to update a string value as I drag the cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a link http://example.com/file01 and I would like to duplicate the link but with the "file01" part increment like "file02", "file03" etc.  So I thought about Excel could do this on an integer cell as I drag the cell lower right hand corner downward.  My question is that how do you do this with a string like in my case?  Thanks!

**Edit**
My apologizes, I acutally needed this url "http://example.com/mp3/file01.mp3" where the "file01" portion requires update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are handled the same as any data type. Just get a solid plus sign on the bottom right corner, and drag it down as general.
[image]
[image]

You can also fill series
[image]

Comment: My apologizes, I acutally needed this url "http://mysite.com/mp3/file01.mp3" where the "file01" portion requires update.

Comment: Just do it my way and then concatenate the results `=concatenate(A1&".mp3")' and drag that

Comment: Thanks Raystafarian for your help and effort. I upvoted and marked you as answer.

Comment: I wish there was an easier way, but I don't know of one, nor can I find one. Maybe someone else will chime in